# how can I create element into other page jquery?

Tags: jquery

when I click on button in first page to create on tag into second page like chat-room that when user type a message and click send button this message show for all people in chat room

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some of the source code form my chat application, there is a lot of work that goes into even a simple chat application: 
http://jamescraig.info/labs/chat/

Also look at the CSS-Tricks tutorial on a simple chat room without the use of a database: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/